# Dictionary true/false error

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm trying to allow the user to change the value for a dictionary, my dictionary is d as follows:

```
   d = {'gary:' : 'B','john:': 'C',}
```

Whenever I type in 'gary:'(gary with a semicolon) for the nameedit input, the why variable will always result in true but regardless, it will read the value as none and never reach the second input for the letter grade(inpu)

```
    nameedit = str(input("Which student do you wish to edit the grade of?"))  
    why = print(nameedit in d)
    if why == None:
        print("That student doesn't exist")
    else:
        inpu = str(input("Enter new letter grade: A,B,C,D,F,"))
        d[nameedit] = inpu 
        print(d)
```

I also tried some variations on this such as if nameedit == True: and an else with the same problem, the print statement will yield True but it will just continue to the else statement. I also tried a elif nameedit in d:

```
  why = print(nameedit in d)
    if nameedit in d == True:
        inpu = str(input("Enter new letter grade: A,B,C,D,F,"))
        d[nameedit] = inpu 
        print(d)            
    else:
        print("That student doesn't exist")
```

, but with no avail. Is it impossible to pick up the value the print statement is reading? My ultimate goal is to simply check if the name is in the dictionary, if it is, continue, if it isn't, stop

python v 3.5

Comment: `print` retrurns `None`. Just do `why = nameedit in d` instead.

Comment: yea i tried that before but it results in the same error, the print statement is just there to result in True to help me confirm that nameedit is equal to a dictionary key, which it does, it turns true(at least for me)

Comment: FYI, Py3's `input` already returns `str`; wrapping in `str` is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
why = nameedit in d
if why:
    inpu = str(input("Enter new letter grade: A,B,C,D,F,"))
    d[nameedit] = inpu 
    print(d)     
else:
    print('Does not exists')
```

Comment: You should explain what they were doing wrong so they understand what mistakes they were making.

Comment: Don't use `d.keys()` for the membership test. `dict` membership testing directly is checking for the presence of a key, so `nameedit in d` is the same logical result, and it's faster to boot (avoids the small cost of constructing the keysview in Py3, and the huge cost of making a shallow copy of the keys as a `list` then scanning it linearly in Py2).

Comment: thank you so much! didn't think of just if why, was trying to use if why = true and if why= none and so many variations, but that makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 0):

`nameedit in d` returns `True` or `False`, never `None`. And wrapping in `print` (which always returns `None`) is just nonsensical.

Remove the `print` wrapping, and change the test to `if not why:` or just move the test into the condition itself:

```
nameedit = input("Which student do you wish to edit the grade of?")
if nameedit not in d:
    print("That student doesn't exist")
else:
    d[nameedit] = input("Enter new letter grade: A,B,C,D,F,")
    print(d)
```

I removed unnecessary `str` wrapping (`input` already returns `str` in Py3), and unnecessary intermediate locals.

Comment: Sorry about that edit.  I thought I was editing my own post.

Comment: @zondo: Yeah, I was a bit confused, since I was making a similar edit when suddenly the post changed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`print()` just puts output to the screen; it does not return what it is printing.  If you want to assign `why` to the result of `nameedit in d` *and* print it; do it on separate lines:

```
why = nameedit in d
print(why)
```

Also, `if ...` is seeing if `...` is `True`.  Using `if ... == True` is seeing if `... == True == True`.  That is redundant.  Just do this:

```
why = nameedit in d
print(why)
if why:
    inpu = input("Enter new letter grade: A,B,C,D,F,")
    d[nameedit] = inpu 
    print(d)            
else:
    print("That student doesn't exist")
```

I also removed your conversion of `input(...)` to a string.  It already returns a string, so the conversion is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Use just like:

```
if why in d:
```

or

```
if why not in d:
```

You don't need use two strings for this. Also, you can get value with get:

```
d = {'gary:' : 'B','john:': 'C',}

name = str(input("Which student do you wish to edit the grade of?\n"))

value = d.get(name, None)

if not value:
    print("That student doesn't exist: {0}: [1}".format(name, value))
else:
    value = str(input("Enter new letter grade: A,B,C,D,F \n"))
    d[name] = value.upper()
    print(d)
```

Comment: Your test is backwards; if the student has a grade, you're saying the student doesn't exist. Also, `.get`'s second argument is implicitly `None` (so no need to pass it), and there are issues with using `if value:` (and even the more correct `if not value:`), because if the `dict` could contain falsy values, this will behave as if the key doesn't exist. Also a little strange to print the `value` when you believe the `value` didn't exist...